# Getting linear-gradient to work in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, linear-gradients

Is there a way to get linear-gradient to work in jQuery? I'm having difficulty getting my code to work getting hidden input values and applying them to a div via inline CSS.

My code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).on( "click", '#update .acf-button-group', function() {
        var color1 = $('#color1 input').val()
        var color2 = $('#color2 input').val()
        $("#output .acf-input").css({"background": "linear-gradient(top, (color1) 0%, (color2) 100%)"});   
    });
});
```

```css
#output .acf-input {height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color1">
<input type="hidden" name="acf[field_60d4d8ef09c78]" value="#0779bf">
</div>
<div id="color2">
<input type="hidden" name="acf[field_61f4e8ef1957b]" value="#48a9e4">
</div>
<div id ="output">
  <div class="acf-input"></div>
</div>
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `to top` instead of `top`.

Also, you need to pass the variable with `` ` `` and `${}`.

Also, `$(document).on( "click", '#update .acf-button-group'` you should pass a Element `$("#update")` instead of `'#update .acf-button-group'`.

After all fix, it should work.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $(document).on("click", $("#update"), function () {
    var color1 = $("#color1 input").val();
    var color2 = $("#color2 input").val();
    //console.log(`linear-gradient(to top, ${color1} 0%, ${color2} 100%)`);
    $("#output .acf-input").css({
      background: `linear-gradient(to top, ${color1} 0%, ${color2} 100%)`,
    });
  });
});

//
```

```css
#output .acf-input {height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color1">
<input type="hidden" name="acf[field_60d4d8ef09c78]" value="#0779bf">
</div>
<div id="color2">
<input type="hidden" name="acf[field_61f4e8ef1957b]" value="#48a9e4">
</div>
<div id ="output">
  <div class="acf-input">xxxxxx</div>
</div>
<button id="update">Update</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linear-gradient(to top,${color1} 0%, ${color2} 100%)` where *color1* & *color2*  will have value of inputs and then set this in your `acf-input` via css.

Demo Code :

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on("click", '#update', function() {
    var color1 = $('#color1 input').val()
    var color2 = $('#color2 input').val()
    var colors = `linear-gradient(to top,${color1} 0%, ${color2} 100%)`;
    console.log(colors)
    $("#output .acf-input").css({
      "background":colors
    });

  });
});
```

```css
#output .acf-input {
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="color1">
  <input type="hidden" name="acf[field_60d4d8ef09c78]" value="#0779bf">
</div>
<div id="color2">
  <input type="hidden" name="acf[field_61f4e8ef1957b]" value="#48a9e4">
</div>
<div id="output">
  <div class="acf-input"></div>
</div>
<button id="update">Update</button>
```